# How to save a number starting with + and has a - in the middle in a .csv file

Tags: excel, csv, excel-2010

I want to insert data to a .csv file in order to keep it formatted similar to the example as follows:

+555-55555555

+197-15464875

---

My .csv file's content:

13,John,Senior,"+555-55555555",20,IT Department

12,Matt,Junior,"+197-15464875",20,Finance

What I get in excel for the numbers respectively:

-55555000

-15464678

Excel assumes that these values are 'numbers' but i want them to be strings. Anyone has any clue?

Comment: Add an apostrophe before the number:  '+555-55555555

Comment: Rename the file replacing csv for txt. Then openin excel and step through the text import wizard. Specify the column in question to be text format. See also: http://jkp-ads.com/articles/importtext.asp

Comment: Probably you are `OPEN`ing the file.  If you `IMPORT` the file, you will be given the opportunity to specify that column as text.  Exactly how to do that depends on your version of Excel.  In the latest update to Office 365 version of Excel 2016, it would be `Data ► Get & Transform Data ► From Text/CSV`, but it is different in earlier versions

Comment: Actually, when I go to `IMPORT` that file, it **does** detect those strings as text, and leaves them unchanged, without any special intervention.